# Tabbed activity with independent activities in Java

Tags: java, android, sql

How can I do a tabbed application for Android with independents ? 
I  tried to use fragments but I cant extend from `AppCompatActivity` with that.

Comment: You do not need to extend from `AppCompatActivity` for individual tabs. Use fragments. The documentation covers [how to do this using `ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), for example.

Comment: i mean i want to know how can i get tabbed aplication without using fragments or use my developed code with appcompactactivity

Comment: There is no supported means of implementing tabs as activities. Your simplest solution is to convert the tab contents to fragments.

Comment: Could you be more specific and give more context?

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way to implement TABS is to use it with FRAGMENTS. It is efficient and reliable.
If you really want to create tabbed layout without fragments then there are two ways:

1) Either you can do this by VISIBILITY functionality of your views ( Show the contents of one tab and hide others , similar for other tabs).

2) Slide the activities when you swipe the screen.